# How to break down an expression into for-loops

Tags: python, for-loop, syntax

I'm not a python expert, and I ran into this snippet of code which actually works and produces the correct answer, but I'm not sure I understand what happens in the second line:

```
for i in range(len(motifs[0])):
            best = ''.join([motifs[j][i] for j in range(len(motifs))])
            profile.append([(best.count(base)+1)/float(len(best)) for base in 'ACGT'])
```

I was trying to replace it with something like:

```
for i in range(len(motifs[0])):
    for j in range(len(motifs)):
        best =[motifs[j][i]]
    profile.append([(best.count(base)+1)/float(len(best)) for base in 'ACGT'])
```

and also tried to break down the last line like this:

```
for i in range(len(motifs[0])):
    for j in range(len(motifs)):
        best =[motifs[j][i]]
    for base in 'ACGT':
        profile.append(best.count(base)+1)/float(len(best)
```

I tried some more variations but non of them worked.
**My question is:** What are those expressions (second and third line of first code) mean and how would you break it down to a few lines?

Thanks :)

Comment: The `[...]` syntax with a for-loop is called a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in range(len(motifs[0])):
            seq = ''.join([motifs[j][i] for j in range(len(motifs))])
            profile.append([(best.count(bseq)+1)/float(len(seq)) for base in 'ACGT'])
```

is equivalent to:

```
for i in range(len(motifs[0])):
    seq = '' 
    for j in range(len(motifs)):
            seq += motifs[j][i] 
    profile.append([(best.count(bseq)+1)/float(len(seq)) for base in 'ACGT'])
```

which can be improved in countless ways.

For example:

```
seqs = [ ''.join(motif) for motif in motifs ]
bc   = best.count(bseq)+1
profilte.extend([ map(lambda x: bc / float(len(x)), 
    seq) for base in 'ACGT' ] for seq in seqs)
```

correctness of which, I cannot test due to lack of input/output conditions.

Comment: see the other answers for some examples, you dont need range generally, instead use enumerate which gives you the index and the item at that index. If you don't need the index, then just use `for item in motifs` construct to get the items only...

Comment: When I try to implement the last segment of code (the improved one) I can't later on use the profile's values as ints because it's a map. (I can't cast it also). Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

```
''.join([motifs[j][i] for j in range(len(motifs))])
```

is idiomatically written

```
''.join(m[i] for m in motifs)
```

so it concatenates the `i`'th entry of all motifs, in order. Similarly,

```
[(best.count(bseq)+1)/float(len(seq)) for base in 'ACGT']
```

builds a list of `(best.count(bseq)+1)/float(len(seq))` values for of `ACGT`; since the `base` variable doesn't actually occur, it's a list containing the same value four times and can be simplified to

```
[(best.count(bseq)+1) / float(len(seq))] * 4
```

Comment: This. Looping over `range(len(something))` is almost always wrong. I recommend watching http://nedbatchelder.com/text/iter.html to anyone who hasn't done so yet.

Comment: "so it concatenates the i'th entry of all motifs, in order." - So in a sense it's like creating an array and transposing it? or am I misinterpreting it?

Answer (score 1):

Closest I got without being able to test it

```
for i, _ in enumerate(motifs[0]):
    seq = ""
    for m in motifs:
        seq += m[i]

    tmp = []
    for base in "ACGT":
        tmp.append(best.count(bseq) + 1 / float(len(seq)))
    profile.append(tmp)
```

Comment: Fixed the second loop

Comment: Yep, and this is why list comprehensions are such a nice thing to have

Comment: Actually that isn't exactly what I needed. my seq now is of varies lengths, and I wanted it to always be of a fixed length (len(motifs))